# Widen exterior door without replacing header

Tags: doors, framing, door-frame

I hired a contractor to replace siding, windows, and doors on my house. It has been a disaster working with these guys... Anyways, a year and a half after I initially ordered the doors, they finally got installed on Friday. My basement exterior door was supposed to be 32 inches wide, but they showed up with a 36 inch wide door. They asked if I wanted the bigger door, and I said go ahead. They widened the door frame, but did not replace the door header. My question is, are there any circumstances in which a header can merely be extended instead of being replaced (in the state of Wisconsin)? My gut tells me no... I pulled some of the Sheetrock back to expose their handiwork. See picture for reference. [image: exposed header]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only only time they would not need to replace the header would be when it is already wide enough and in the correct location.  (eg if there had previously been a wide-enough doorway at that locations) Or possibly if they used a flitch plate or similar engineered solution  to extend the header.

To answer the question implied but not asked,  what you currently have is no good and the simplest way to fix it is to install a longer header.

Comment: I'm assuming that in order to replace the header, a temporary wall would be required?

Comment: yes, temporary framing or jack posts etc.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in other answers, no, this is *not* correct, nor is it acceptable!

If you cannot get them to come back to do it right, tell them your next call is to your local licensing board (they're a licensed and insured contractor, right?) to file a complaint. That *should* motivate them to do the job right.

While replacing a door should not require a permit, this is a structural change that probably would have, consider calling your local building inspector. You may have to pay for a permit, and maybe even a fine for not getting the permit before hand, but that would be cheaper than paying out of pocket for repair work for when (not if) this fails and the insurance company denies the claim.

Answer (score 0):

The lintel (header) has two purposes.

1. Take the load from a load bearing wall to the sides of the portal
2. Stop doors and windows jamming from deflections (bending) of the frame above

Point 1 is more serious and you need to eliminate that.  Regardless, if it was me, I would be replacing it with a longer one.